# Can skeletons see normally?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead, vision-and-light

They don't have eyes. The magic that animates them also gives them darkvision, but can they also see normally and react to things further away than 60 feet?

‍‌​

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Can a creature with blindsight that is not immune to the Blinded condition suffer the effects of Blindness?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/91773/9399) (If this is asking what I think it's asking, [my answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/91774/9399) on that question also potentially answers this question.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### The Skeleton can see beyond that

If the skeleton was blind beyond its darkvision range, it would be annotated as such - see the oozes in *Monster Manual* for examples of monsters with this sight modifier. Since the skeleton lacks such note, it can see beyond the range of its 60 foot darkvision.

Comment: TBH, this is no different than Dwarves or other darkvision creatures.  They have darkvision to X range, and normal vision beyond it.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Yeah, skeletons are not really exceptional in this regard.

Comment: Blind skeletons would be quite atmospheric and creepy.